# How can I redirect from a controller with a value to another controller in laravel?

Tags: laravel, https, controller, routes, payment-processing

`OrderController.php`

```php
if (request('payment_method') == 'online') {
    return redirect(route('payments.pay', $order->id));
}
```

`web.php`

```php
Route::POST('/pay/{orderId}', 'PublicSslCommerzPaymentController@index')->name('payments.pay');
```

`PublicSslCommerzPaymentController.php`

```php
session_start();
class PublicSslCommerzPaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, $ordId)
    {
       //code...
    }
}
```

> Here in index function I need the order id from `OrderController.

`But the Error I am getting`

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: `payments.pay` is the post method and while you redirect from the controller it is called get method. so you need to change in route as GET method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to redirect to named route you can use this:

```
return redirect()->route('payments.pay', ['orderId' => $order->id]);
```

if you want generate redirect to controller action you can try this:

```
return redirect()->action(
    'PublicSslCommerzPaymentController@index', ['ordId' => $order->id]]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your web.php from **POST** method to **GET** method

**Something like this**

```
Route::GET('/pay/{orderId}', 'PublicSslCommerzPaymentController@index')->name('payments.pay');
```